# An unexpected result of simulation ion trajectory, by applying stored waveform inverse Fourier transform (SWIFT)

Tags: matlab

I've recently conducted a simulation involving a SWIFT waveform applied to an ion trap featuring two notches. Specifically, these notches correspond to the ion secular frequency. According to theory, ions within the notch frequency range should not be excited by the SWIFT waveform. However, in my case, I observed that the ions did indeed get excited.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw8FL.png)

The expected results should show ions without excitation in the output.